# Linux server issue one way ping

Tags: linux, networking

I am new to Linux and am working on this project which has a linux server and windows hosts. configuration is as follows:

linux server: 10.10.10.177/24
default route to gw 10.10.10.1

windows host: 10.20.20.253/24
default route to gw 10.20.20.1

both the gateways are on the same L3-switch. VLAN 23 is 10.10.10.1 & VLAN 99 is 10.20.20.1.

**Here's the issue:**
from the server i can ping the gateways and the host as well. but the host can't ping the server. the host can ping the gateways.

during troubleshooting, i removed the servers cable from switch port and connected my 
laptop to the switch. doing this, the windows host can ping my laptop !?!

i have added a default route on the linux server 
route add default gw 10.10.10.1

still no use :(

if anyone out there can help, i'd greatly appreciate.

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route show` in the GNU/Linux server to your question

Comment: I suspect the Linux server is running a local firewall, which is blocking the ping from the Windows host.

Comment: Have the exceptions been made in all firewalls or are they turned off?

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a firewall blocking your ping requests on either the gateway or the linux server. Routers typically block the ICMP protocol ports (required to complete a ping request). However, ping isn't the only way to "locate" your server from your host. You may alternately try one of these methods:

1) If you have a HTTP web-server running on the server, run “telnet 10.10.10.177 80″ from the command line on your host. This checks for an open service on port 80 (HTTP). If the telnet request succeeds, you have the connectivity.

2) If you have internet running on the server, then you can install a proxy server such as squid on the server and try to connect to internet from the host machine.

3) Similar telnet requests can be sent to ports 443, 21 and 25 for HTTPS, FTP & SMTP services respectively (if you have any of these services running on the server).

Comment: Routers typically DO NOT typically block ICMP protocol ports.  ICMP doesn't have the concept of port numbers for starters.  If ICMP was blocked on most routers, you couldn't ping much at all.  Actually it's end user routers that block ICMP.

Comment: ICMP has a type field which I think is what you mean by icmp protocol ports.